# Calling child method from parent, when parent method is called from child

Tags: ruby

There are 2 Ruby classes:

```
class Parent
  class << self
    def method1
      ...
    end

    def method2
      ...
      method1
      ...
    end
  end
end

class Child < Parent
  class << self
    def method1
      ...
    end

    def method2
      ...
      super
    end
  end
end
```

Class `Child` is inherited from `Parent` and redefines its methods `method1` and `method2`. `Method2` of class `Parent` is called from the same method in `Child` (using `super` keyword). I want that when called from `Child` (ie `Child.method2`), it will use `method1` of `Child`. Instead, it uses `method1` of `Parent`. It's understandable but not desirable.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I ran your code with some puts:

```
class Parent
  class << self
    def method1
        puts "parent.method1; self: #{self.inspect}"
    end

    def method2
        puts "parent.method2 before method1 call; self: #{self.inspect}"
        method1
        puts "parent.method2 after method1 call"
    end
  end
end

class Child < Parent
  class << self
    def method1
        puts "child.method1; self: #{self.inspect}"
    end

    def method2
        puts "child.method2 before super; self: #{self.inspect}"
        super
        puts "child.method2 after super"
    end
  end
end


Child.method2
```

and this is what I got:

**Output**:

```
child.method2 before super; self: Child
parent.method2 before method1 call; self: Child
child.method1; self: Child
parent.method2 after method1 call
child.method2 after super
```

Is this not what you wanted?

Ruby handles method resolution with the target always being the class of the object. In the code above, even when being called with super, the class is still child. So it will call any method defined on child, and then on parent if it isn't found, or if child calls super...

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. It's a shame but occasionally my results were different initially.